# Trouble Inserting Dataset data into Database table

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I have used this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5976/SQLDataAdapter-without-using-SQLCommandBuilder) to figure out how to do this. But my problem is that it does not work. This is my code:

```
public void UpdateDatabase(DataSet data, string tableName)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDbOnBrie"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.TransportSchedule_Customer;", connection))
            {
                using (SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.TransportSchedule_Customer SET Alias=@Alias, DeliveryDays1=@DeliveryDays1, DeliveryHours1=@DeliveryHours1, DeliveryType1=@DeliveryType1, DeliveryDays2=@DeliveryDays2, DeliveryHours2=@DeliveryHours2, DeliveryType2=@DeliveryType2, DeliveryDays3=@DeliveryDays3, DeliveryHours3=@DeliveryHours3, DeliveryType3=@DeliveryType3,  DistanceToDealer=@DistanceToDealer WHERE AdrID=@AdrID AND CustID=@CustID", connection))
                {
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@CustID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "CustID");
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@AdrID", SqlDbType.Int, 50,"AdrID");
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Alias", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Alias");

                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@DeliveryDays1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "DeliveryDays1");
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@DeliveryHours1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "DeliveryHours1");
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@DeliveryType1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "DeliveryType1");

                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@DeliveryDays2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "DeliveryDays2");
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@DeliveryHours2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "DeliveryHours2");
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@DeliveryType2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "DeliveryType2");

                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@DeliveryDays3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "DeliveryDays3");
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@DeliveryHours3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "DeliveryHours3");
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@DeliveryType3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "DeliveryType3");

                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Alias", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Alias");

                    adapter.UpdateCommand = updateCmd;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR in UpdateDatabase() method. Error Message : " + exception.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs without any errors, but my database table does not get updated with the new information. I can see that the Dataset has the right information which it retrieves from my Excel file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forget to call `Update` method for updating data in you cod that might be a problem here

check the link give by you there is method used for update like this

```
sqlDa.Update(dSet,"emp");
```

which do update in database.

---

**MSDN**

[DataAdapter.Update Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx)- Calls the respective `INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE` statements for each `inserted, updated, or deleted` row in the specified `DataSet` from a `DataTable` named "`Table`."